# Sqlite, csv: Unicode Encoding Error

Tags: python-2.7, csv, unicode, sqlite

I want to store unicode values in SQLite Database.
The data is copied from csv file. Here is the Sqlite code

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
create Table WAY_TAGS_v1(id INTEGER,
key TEXT,
value TEXT, 
type TEXT);

.mode csv 
.import 'test_unicode.csv' WAY_TAGS_v1
```

The csv file(test_unicode.csv) Data:

```
id,key,value,type
1,te,తెలుగు,mahi
1,te,ఇది,virat
```

But when I save the csv file, and re-open, the values are lost

```
id,key,value,type
1,te,??????,mahi
1,te,???,virat
```

And then, with this set of values, I am unable to store it in SQLite Database

How can I ensure that in SQlite database, I can store the right values in Unicode format

Comment: SQLite does not change the bytes that make up a string. What do you mean with "save" and "re-open"? Are you using the Windows console?

Comment: @CL. save and re-open the csv file